# Cookies not being saved in different browsers

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, session-cookies

I'm facing a big issue, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge won't let me browser my website correctly.

Whenever I click a link on it will kick me out to the login page, I've tried this in a coworker computer and well it kicks him right into the login page also, BUT the tricky part is that in someone else computer it might take a few tries in IE to get it to work and actually we all got it to work after a couple of logouts/logins attempts, now everything is browsing correctly, but we're facing this issue with other co-workers that haven't done this trial and error situation and well most of them don't wish to do so, so we got to make it work. Driving me crazy because another user reported it worked like a charm on IE since always so, we cleared cookies and everything, tried again on his computer and it worked.

In Microsoft Edge(Used different versions with other co-workers, all of them won't work) and Safari are completely broken, anything you click will kick you out of the website to the login website.

Website is built in ASP.NET Webforms.

Appreciate your time for reading this.
Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Is there a way to solve this?

We're not facing this issues in Chrome nor Firefox

Comment: We had something similar, it was killing the session and forcing the user to log back in each time.   It was due to the SameSite attribute not being used by certain cookies.  Oddly though, our issue was mainly on Chrome and not other browsers. So maybe a different issue, but good luck.

Comment: We've tried several changes we've seen here in stack in the Web.config that kind of relate to this issue but none of them seem to fix the issue and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't this is nutz